# Unable to resolve argument php-oci8 - Centos 7

Tags: php, instantclient

Ive been using this my dokcerfile for years now and not having an issue but today when I tried to rebuild my docker container. I got an error of . im using php7.4 with oci8

```
Argument 'php-oci8' matches 2 streams ('21c', '21c-3.0.1') of module 'php-oci8', but none of the streams are enabled or default
Unable to resolve argument php-oci8
Error: Problems in request:
broken groups or modules: php-oci8
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-php:7.4-fpm


RUN dnf install -y epel-release
# RUN yum update -y 
RUN yum install -y supervisor
RUN yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum

RUN dnf -y module enable nginx && dnf -y install nginx && rm -rf /var/cache/dnf && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
RUN dnf install -y oraclelinux-developer-release-el8 oracle-instantclient-release-el8 libpng-devel libzip-devel
RUN dnf module enable -y php:7.4 php-oci8
RUN dnf install -y php php-oci8-21c
RUN dnf install -y php-fpm php-pdo php-pdo_mysql php-zip php-gd php-json php-openssl php-curl php-tokenizer php-dom php-opcache php-pear
RUN dnf install -y git unzip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN sed -i "s/listen = 0.0.0.0:9000/listen = 0.0.0.0:9004/g" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

ADD ./dockerfiles/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/transco-fitall-ep
WORKDIR /var/www/transco-fitall-ep

ARG UID
ARG GID

ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}

RUN groupadd -g ${GID} --system laravel
RUN adduser -g laravel --system -s /bin/sh -u ${UID} laravel

RUN sed -i "s/user = apache/user = laravel/g" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = apache/group = laravel/g" /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

COPY --chown=laravel:laravel . /var/www/transco-fitall-ep

# RUN chown -R laravel:laravel /var/www/transco-fitall-ep

EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 8082

# STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT

ADD ./dockerfiles/supervisord.ini /etc/supervisord.d/supervisord.ini

CMD ["supervisord","-n"]
```